# Как отслеживать координаты Обьекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, объекты, координаты

Мне для игры нужно сделать 3D миникарту, но не знаю как отслеживать все координаты персонажа. Игра на C#, Unity

Comment: Мало информации о том чего вы добиваетесь. В каком виде ваша 3D карта: это отдельная камера с высоты птичьего полета, или текстура поверх которой вы хотите значки показывать. А может у вас вообще радар на котором только позиции объектов показываются относительно вас?

Answer (score 0):

Обычно делают некий **RenderTarget** для мини карты, на каждый объект крепят маркеры которые по слоям визуализируются для вашей мини карты, а для основной камеры слои отключены. Я скину вам урок по [Мини картам](https://youtu.be/kWhOMJMihC0).

Answer (score -1):

```
GameObject.Find("Your_Name_Here").transfor
```